# Cannot consume scoped service MyDbContext from singleton - InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, dbcontext

My project is .net core 2 base, i set context and repository in startup.cs file

```
services.AddDbContext<DocumentContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
services.AddSingleton<IAuthRepository, AuthRepository>();
```

IAuthRepository file :

```
public interface IAuthRepository
{
    int Login(LoginRequest model);
    int Register(RegisterRequest model);
}
```

AuthRepository file :

```
private readonly DocumentContext db;
public AuthRepository(DocumentContext context)
{
    this.db = context;
}
...
```

Controller:

```
private IAuthRepository AuthMethod { get; set; }
public AuthController(IAuthRepository authMethod)
{
    this.AuthMethod = authMethod;
}
```

I get this error

> InvalidOperationException: Cannot consume scoped service '...DocumentContext' from singleton '...IAuthRepository'.

Comment: singletons can't have dependencies that are scoped (per HTTP request)

Comment: please explain more, what i need to change ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.1#service-lifetimes

Comment: if you can, help me by code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, this is pretty common to trip over in asp.net core, and there is a full article about it in [dotnetcoretutorials](https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2018/03/20/cannot-consume-scoped-service-from-singleton-a-lesson-in-asp-net-core-di-scopes/):

> ...because it’s actually the Service DI of ASP.net
>   Core trying to make sure you don’t trip yourself up. Although it’s not
>   foolproof (They still give you enough rope to hang yourself), it’s
>   actually trying to stop you making a classic DI scope mistake.

the conclusion at the end of it all is simple: **because the ChildService is scoped, but the FatherService is singleton, it’s not going to allow us to run**:

> ...is that transient is “everytime this service is requested, create a
>   new instance”, so technically this is correct behaviour (Even though
>   it’s likely to cause issues). Whereas a “scoped” instance in ASP.net
>   Core is “a new instance per page request” which cannot be fulfilled
>   when the parent is singleton.